# Open file with vi in konsole by default

Tags: files, editors, konsole, events

I am running Fedora 32 with KDE env.

In dolphin, I would like to open '.m' files using vi in konsole by simply clicking on this file.
In short, if my file is "toto.m", I want  the command "konsole -e 'vi toto.m'" to be executed when I click on this type of file.

I tried to manage "File options" with no success.

I tried to create a personal script:

```
#!/bin/zsh

namfil="$1"
konsole -e 'vi $namfil'"
```

but failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under KDE system settings (`systemsettings5`) > "Application" > "File Association" > "Add" > Select "text" group and name your files type then hit "Ok".

Under the newly added type, add `*.m` to the "Filename Patterns" then bellow under "Application Preference Order" add `konsole -e 'vi %U'`

[image]